# Expectation of cubic form (covariance between a quadratic form and a dot product)

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, covariance, expected-value

Consider a $n$-dimensional random vector $X$ with mean $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbf{0}$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Given a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and a $n$-dimensional vector $b$, is there any explicit expression for the following quantity 
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X^T A X, b^T X)=\mathbb{E}[ (X^TAX) (b^TX)] \text{ ?}
$$

Comment: This will involve third order moments of components of $X$, which you cannot obtain from only the mean and covariance matrix.

Comment: Agreed. Assuming that you know everything about the 3rd order moments of $X$, what can be said?

Comment: You could write out the matrix multiplication as $(\sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} x_i x_j)(\sum_k b_k x_k)$, multiply through, collect terms, and use whatever information you have about $E[x_i x_j x_k]$.